# NIFI for heterogeneous clusters

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I am new to NIFI and trying to understand its architecture. 
From what I understood, the primary node in the cluster is selected internally by the system and user has no control over it. Also, we can configure some processors to run only on Primary Node (Isolated Processors).

My doubt is that if my cluster is heterogeneous and I want to run the Isolated (CPU-intensive) processors on the powerful node, is it possible to configure that node as primary?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it the primary node is automatically chosen by the NiFi cluster and you cannot choose which node it is. If the primary node goes down, then a new node will be elected as primary.

Generally the concept of primary node is used to trigger source processors that you would only want to execute once. For example, when using ListSFTP you would likely want to run this on primary node only, otherwise all the nodes in your cluster are going to list the same files.